# How to only labeling points that have text in the "name" field and not with null values?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Labeling with " "name" is not null" only gives me numbers 1 or 0.

I want to label only the features with values in the field "name".

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the "show label" expression (under Rendering) to `"name" is not null` and the label to `"name"`.

[image]